An alternative to Levenberg–Marquardt algorithm
When trying to solve for a (over)determined non-linear least square method:
$$\underset{x}{\min}||f(x)||^2_2, f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m, x\in \mathbb{R}^n, m\geq n$$
we use the Gauss-Newton algorithm to solve it iteratively.
At each iteration $k\in\mathbb{N}$, the system is linearized at the current iteration of the independent variables $x_k$, using the Taylor expansion and discarding the higher order terms:
$$f(x)\approx f(x_k)+J(x_k)(x-x_k)$$
where $J(x_k)\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ is the jacobian matrix of $f(x)$ with respect to $x$, evaluated at $x_k$. It becomes a linear least-square problem:
$$\underset{x}{\min}||f(x_k)+J(x_k)(x-x_k)||^2_2 = \underset{x}{\min} (f-Jx_k)^T(f-Jx_k) + 2x^TJ^T(f-Jx_k) + x^TJ^TJx$$
The right-hand side is after expansion and the calculation of the 2-norm. Sorry for the abuse of notation here by dropping the $(x_k)$. This minimization has a closed-form solution by taking the derivative with respect to $x$ and setting the result to be $0$:
$$J^TJx+J^T(f-Jx_k)\stackrel{!}{=} 0$$
In the case where $J$ is full column rank and $J^TJ$ is invertible, the result would be:
$$x_{k+1} = -(J^TJ)^{-1}J^T(f-Jx_k)=x_k -(J^TJ)^{-1}J^Tf$$
This is the Gauss-Newton algorithm. In the case where $J$ is not full column rank and $J^TJ$ becomes non-invertible, the Levenberg–Marquardt algorithm proposes adding a regularization term to the objective:
$$\underset{x}{\min}||f(x_k)+J(x_k)(x-x_k)||^2_2 + \lambda||x-x_k||^2_2$$
The solution to this minimization becomes:
$$x_{k+1} = x_k -(J^TJ+\lambda I)^{-1}J^Tf$$
where $(J^TJ+\lambda I)$ becomes invertible.
My question is, after such a long bedding: at step $k$, after the linearization:
$$f(x)\approx f(x_k)+J(x_k)(x-x_k)=J(x_k)x + f(x_k) - J(x_k)x_k$$
Can we directly equate this function to $0$ and solve for $x$ in the least-square sense by taking the pseudo-inverse of $J(x_k)$?
$$J(x_k)x + f(x_k) - J(x_k)x_k \stackrel{!}{=} 0$$
$$x_{Least square} = J^{\dagger}(x_k)J(x_k)x_k-J^{\dagger}(x_k) f(x_k)$$
Doing this does not require $J(x_k)$ to be full column rank. It does not even need the system to be over(determined) because the pseudo-inverse can be found anyway using the SVD decomposition. It becomes the Gauss-Newton algorithm when $J$ is full column rank. Would it be a more general solution to tackle rank deficiency in the Gauss-Newton algorithm?
